# Error when running Integration test in Flutter using patrol

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-integration-test, flutter-patrol

I'm trying to run an integration test in flutter using the [patrol 1.0.8](https://pub.dev/packages/patrol) package.
Then I got an error when running the test with commanded `patrol test integration_test/classic_process_test.dart --verbose`  on ios physical device.

Error is `Error: No .xctestrun file was found at ~/projectName/build/ios_integ/Build/Products`

Here is my code:

```
import 'package: projectName/main.dart';
import 'package:patrol/patrol.dart';

void main() async{
  patrolTest('Test classic account process', nativeAutomation: true, (PatrolTester    $) async{

await $.pumpWidgetAndSettle(MyApp());


await $(#slide1).scrollTo(duration: Duration(seconds: 1), step: -300, maxScrolls: 0);
await $(#slide2).scrollTo(duration: Duration(seconds: 1), step: -300, maxScrolls: 300);
await $(#slide3).tap();

await $(#KeysStrings.I_AM_NEW).tap();
await $(#KeysStrings.LASTNAME_KEY).enterText("Babacar");
await $(#KeysStrings.FIRSTNAME_KEY).enterText("Test auto");
await $(#KeysStrings.PHONE_NUMBER_KEY).enterText("760123456");
await $(#KeysStrings.SUBMIT_REGISTER_FORM_KEY).tap();


await $(#KeysStrings.TAKE_HOME_PICTURE_KEY).tap();


await $(#KeysStrings.HAVE_HOME_NUMBER).tap();
await $(#KeysStrings.HOME_NUMBER_FIELD_KEY).enterText("122e");
await $(#KeysStrings.SUBMIT_HOME_NUMBER_KEY).tap();


await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10));
await $(#KeysStrings.GENERATE_ADDRESS_BUTTON_KEY).tap();
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));


await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10));
await $(#KeysStrings.GET_PLATE_BUTTON_KEY1).tap();


await $(#KeysStrings.CHOOSE_PAYMENT_MOMENT).tap();
await $(#KeysStrings.CHOOSE_PAYMENT_METHOD).tap();
await $(#KeysStrings.VALIDATE_PAYMENT_BUTTON).tap();
await $(#KeysStrings.CONTINUE_AFTER_ENTER_AMOUNT).tap();
 });
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in `patrol_cli`. It was also reported [here](https://github.com/leancodepl/patrol/issues/1105).

It's been fixed since [patrol_cli v1.1.1](https://pub.dev/packages/patrol_cli/changelog#111). Run `patrol update` to make sure you're on the latest `patrol_cli` version.